# Max Input Time best place to set it in PHP code

Tags: php

So I have an application where we allowing the upload of very large files in just one spot. So a typical post is made to the function media_gallery_upload().

```
function media_gallery_upload()
{
    ini_set('max_input_time', 1200);
    $parts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
}
```

Will it work to set the ini_set() in that section of the function?

Or is the file being uploaded have to finish uploading to temporary memory before it even runs ini_set(), in which case setting it there would mean nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, this won't have any effect on at all. It only afects the parsing of input data. I've never bothered with this setting,

Looking at the manual, it seems to be difficult to manage this setting at runtime since it's used before the actual execution of the script.